# Convert Discriminated Union to primitive type via member function in F#

Tags: f#

I have the following discriminated union with a member function where I want to return the unboxed type:

```
type ModelData =
    | Double of double
    | UInt32 of uint32
    | UInt16 of uint16
    | Byte of byte
    | Int32 of int32
    | String of string
    | Bit of Bit
    member inline this.Value : 'a =
        match this with
        | Double x -> x
        | UInt32 x -> x
        | UInt16 x -> x
        | Byte x -> x
        | Int32 x -> x
        | String x -> x
        | Bit x -> x
```

The error is that the member 'this.Value' doesn't return the same type for each branch. Is this possible?

**Edit #1**

I have a Database defined as follows which uses this `ModelData` type:

```
module Database =
    type Drecord =
        { Value: ModelData}
    type Db = Dictionary<string, Drecord>
```

So I have a database full of values, then I take some of these values and generate a JSON string using sprintf.

```
sprintf "{\"General\":{\"Example\":%.3f}}" value //where value is of type ModelData
```

This currently does not work since sprintf requires a `float` and not a `ModelData`. So original I thought I could call a function to safely convert to that type (hence the `this.Value` member). I've got this to work by having `this.Value` instead return a string, and having only `%s` in my sprintf format string.
So this works:

```
sprintf "{\"General\":{\"Example\":%s}}" value.Value
```

Is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: This is [an XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You're trying to do something that doesn't make sense, probably in order to solve a problem that does. We could most likely help you solve that problem, but you'd have to tell us what it is first.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand what are you trying to do. If you define a discriminated union, then the value can be either of the cases and when you want to use a value of your `ModelData` type, you'll need to pattern match on it in order to decide what kind of value you have.

If you add a way of getting a value that works only for one specific case (e.g. when the value is a `float`), you are losing all the safety that discriminated unions give you. So, I think that doing what you're asking for is most likely going to be a bad idea.

That said, you can define a member `GetValue<'a>` that can be called to extract value of a specific type using the `unbox` function:

```
type ModelData =
    | Double of double
    | UInt32 of uint32
    | UInt16 of uint16
    member inline this.GetValue<'a>() : 'a =
        match this with
        | Double x -> unbox<'a> x
        | UInt32 x -> unbox<'a> x
        | UInt16 x -> unbox<'a> x

let v = Double 1.23
v.GetValue<float>()
```

This will, of course, throw an `InvalidCastException` if you call it with the wrong type argument, e.g. `v.GetValue<int>()` in the above case. Also note that this needs to be a method so that you can make it generic.